# Are variable definitions that are used once optimized?

Tags: java, variables, optimization

Consider the following method:

```
private static long maskAndNegate(long l) {
    int numberOfLeadingZeros = Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(l)
    long mask = CustomBitSet.masks[numberOfLeadingZeros];
    long result = (~l) & mask;
    return result;
}
```

The method can be abbreviated to:

```
private static long maskAndNegate(long l) {
    return (~l) & CustomBitSet.masks[Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(l)];
}
```

Are these two representations equal in actual run time? In other words, does the Java compiler optimize away the unnecessary definition of extra variables, that I've placed for  readability and debugging?

Comment: Which Java compiler? Which JIT compiler? Which platform? In other words, the only reliable way to get an answer that's relevant to *you* is by testing this yourself. It's not that hard.

Comment: "does the Java compiler optimize..." in most cases, the compiler does not optimize things ever, iirc. the HotSpot technology may optimize it, and is probably what you should research.

Comment: There are some optimizations that are done by most - if not all - Java compilers. I'll take any optimization that's done by Oracle, GNU (and perhaps Eclipse) as standard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler#Major_Java_compilers

Comment: Compile both versions. Then use the `javap` tool (included with the JDK) to disassemble the class files (use the `-c` option of `javap`). Compare the byte code to see the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Java compiler itself hardly does any optimization. It's the JIT that does almost everything.

Local variables themselves are somewhat irrelevant to optimization though - a multi-operator expression still needs the various operands *logically* to go on the stack, just in unnamed "slots". You may well find that the generated bytecode for your two implementations if very similar, just without the names in the second case.

More importantly, any performance benefit that *might* occur *very occasionally* from reducing the number of local variables you use is almost certainly going to be insignificant. The readability benefit of the first method is much more likely to be significant. As always, avoid micro-optimizing without first having evidence that the place you're trying to optimize is a bottleneck, and then only allow optimizations which have *proved* their worth.

(By the time you've proved you *need* to optimize a particular method, you'll already have the tools to test any potential optimization, so you won't need to guess.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was asking out of curiosity - I always prefer readability over minor, premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not significantly large enough to be optimized for starters. And in the second way you are just saving the memory used for storing references to `numberOfLeadingZeros` and all.

But when you will use this code significantly enough on runtime such as 10000 times at least, then JIT will identify it as HOT code and then optimize it with neat tricks such as Method Inlining and similar sorts.

But in your case **preferable option is first one** as it is more **readable**.

*You should not compromise Readability for small optimizations.*