# `if` condition efficiency

Tags: java, performance

I'm working on improving the performance of a `Java` program.
After I've improved the `data structures` and the algorithm's complexity, I'm trying to improve the implementation. I want to know if it really matters how I use the `if` statement in condition.

Does the compiler treat these two versions the same? Do they cost the same (If I have much more variables inside the `if` statement)?

```
if(a && b && c && d && e && f && g)
```

**OR**

```
if(a)
 if(b)
  if(c)
   if(d)
    if(e)
     if(f)
      if(g)
```

(*In this specific project I don't really care about readability, I know the second is less readable*)

Comment: Even before you get to the compiler optimization issue, the second version is definitely less readable.

Comment: You are right, but in this specific project I care less about the readability, I just want to use the more efficient implementation since it is extremely critical for me in this case.

Comment: Look this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621324/are-variable-definitions-that-are-used-once-optimized/13621403#13621403). It can be transferred to your case.

Comment: use profiler for finding the performance leakages, its not if condition will degrad the performance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `&&` operator (and also `||`) is a **short-circuit** operator in Java.

That means that if `a` is `false`, Java doesn't evaluate `b`, `c`, `d` etc., because it already knows the whole expression `a && b && c && d && e && f && g` is going to be `false`.

So there is nothing to be gained to write your `if` as a series of nested `if` statements.

The only good way to optimize for performance is by measuring the performance of a program using a profiler, determining where the actual performance bottleneck is, and trying to improve that part of the code. Optimizing by inspecting code and guessing, and then applying micro-optimizations, is usually not an effective way of optimizing.

Comment: Did you mean `||`? Because If `a` is `true` Java continues to evaluate `a && b && c && d && e && f && g1`. If `a` is `false` then it knows `a && b && c && d && e && f && g1` will be false.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers, even on a very low level there is no difference between the two approaches - they are compiled into the same bytecode:

```
boolean a=true, b=true, c=true, d=true, e=true, f=true, g=true;
   0: iconst_1
   1: istore_1
   2: iconst_1
   3: istore_2
   4: iconst_1
   5: istore_3
   6: iconst_1
   7: istore        4
   9: iconst_1
  10: istore        5
  12: iconst_1
  13: istore        6
  15: iconst_1
  16: istore        7

if(a && b && c && d && e && f && g) {}
  18: iload_1
  19: ifeq          45
  22: iload_2
  23: ifeq          45
  26: iload_3
  27: ifeq          45
  30: iload         4
  32: ifeq          45
  35: iload         5
  37: ifeq          45
  40: iload         6
  42: ifeq          45

if(a) if(b) if(c) if(d) if(e) if(f) if(g) {}
  45: iload_1
  46: ifeq          72
  49: iload_2
  50: ifeq          72
  53: iload_3
  54: ifeq          72
  57: iload         4
  59: ifeq          72
  62: iload         5
  64: ifeq          72
  67: iload         6
  69: ifeq          72
```

Answer (score 6):

When profiling a program written in any language, do not focus on language structures, but focus on what your code is doing.  Time your code, find out where the time is spent, then you will know what's the cause because it would have been narrowed down.

If you know that the slow parts of your program are in your if statement, then you already know the answer to your question.

I'm posting this as an answer because I believe asking about the efficiency of a particular language feature for optimization purposes is entirely the wrong approach, and I believe you would benefit from a much different strategy.

Also, certain implementations may handle things a bit differently, so unless something is set in stone in a standard (and sometimes, even THAT is no guarantee), the answer could be implementation dependent, and conditional.