# Local variables: Programming Practices

Tags: java, methods

Given the following methods:

```
public int methodOne() {
    int total = local_int_one + local_int_two;
    return total;
}

public int methodTwo() {
    return local_int_one + local_int_two;
}
```

1) Is the only difference in the above methods readability or is there a micro-optimization "benefit" in methodTwo()?

2) Should the defining of local variables in a narrow scope be shunned and avoided when possible? (I can see methodTwo becoming unreadable if several calculations must be performed in a single statement)

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: Check the byte code. (2) has one less instruction.

Comment: @EJP: what if you turn on optimizations? Currently I have no access to a java bytecode viewer. But evidently debug mode results in some sort of one-on-one mapping.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621324/are-variable-definitions-that-are-used-once-optimized

Comment: @Commusoft The Java compiler does little or nothing in the way of optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: `methodTwo()` is *slightly* more efficient.

`methodOne()` results in the following bytecode:

```
public int methodOne();
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  getfield com.example.Test.local_int_one : int [13]
 4  aload_0 [this]
 5  getfield com.example.Test.local_int_two : int [15]
 8  iadd
 9  istore_1 [total]
10  iload_1 [total]
11  ireturn
```

And here's the bytecode for `methodTwo()`:

```
public int methodTwo();
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  getfield com.example.Test.local_int_one : int [13]
 4  aload_0 [this]
 5  getfield com.example.Test.local_int_two : int [15]
 8  iadd
 9  ireturn
```

But note that this optimization is *too minor*, and that code readability in this case matters a lot more then a couple of java instructions.

If you think a temporary variable will contribute to code readability, then, by all means, use it.

Comment: Almost two years later, I'd like to add a follow-up here if I may. Since methodTwo() does not perform istore_1, does this mean that (in Java) there would be no additional gc step to perform (since the value is just returned and not stored)? ... so in a gc-critical environment, instantiating variables in small scopes should be shunned?

Comment: @mcw, integers aren't subject to garbage collection, nor the local variables. As for objects - they are created on heap in any case https://stackoverflow.com/a/27587519/2170192